# How to get BGCOLOR of a TD?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the value of bgcolor? (my alert is wrong).

```
<table id="mytable1" onclick="setColor()" width="25" border-color:black border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpading="0" align="left">
    <tr>
          <td id='colorId' bgcolor=yellow>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("colorId").GetAttribute('bgcolor'));
</script>
```

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Depends on the DOCTYPE.

Comment: No, it is deprecated (period). The Doctype just determines if it is valid in the chosen markup language (and deprecated features tend not to appear in Strict Doctypes).

Comment: @David Thinking it through again: yes I agree. While being valid in certain doctypes, it is a deprecated feature, and should not be used on future-aware sites.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is case-sensitive. `getAttribute()` should be written with a lowercase `g` (like `getElementById` and all others). This is called **camel-case** (or camelCase and then the name says what it is), Javascript functions follow this naming convention.

```
document.getElementById("colorId").getAttribute('bgcolor')
```

Also you can't write CSS directly to a HTML element, you have to use the `style` attribute:

```
style="border-color: black;"
```

One more thing, if you let me. Try to be consistent in your markup style. In HTML4/5 you can use either `'`, `"` or nothing around your attribute values (like `id="colorId"`, `id='colorId'` or `id=colorId`), you should stick to one of these in the same HTML page (not that you cannot mix them, but staying consistent is considered a better practice).

Answer (score 1):

`getAttribute` not `GetAttribute`